# When using logstash to index data from MySQL to ElasticSearch,only the first row is being displayed

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch, logstash

This is my logstash configuration file:

```
          input
    {
        jdbc 
        {

         jdbc_driver_library => "/home/vatsa/logstash/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar"


         jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

         jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stud"

         jdbc_user => "root"
         jdbc_password => ""
          statement => "select * from det"
       }
    }
  output  

 {
  elasticsearch 
    {

    index => "det"
    document_type => "contact"
    document_id => "%{uid}"
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
}stdout { codec => json_lines }
}
```

Logstash startup and shutdown is created.But when i do a get request using,

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/det/_search?pretty&q=*'
```

this is the output:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : 
[   {
      "_index" : "det",
      "_type" : "contact",
      "_id" : "%{uid}",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"ID":5,"NAME":"SHUBH","USN":"099","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-01-26T05:42:08.362Z"}
    } ]
  }
```

But there are 5 entities in the table.What is the reason for this??How to solve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your indexed document, it has its `_id` set to `"%{uid}"`, which means that in your SQL table you don't have any `uid` field that can be used as the ID of the document in Elasticsearch, as a result, the string `%{uid}` is set as the ID.

Since each indexed document gets the same ID, it overrides the previous one with that ID, hence why you only see one document.

Try to make sure you either have a `uid` field in your `det` SQL table or use the proper ID field as the `document_id` parameter in your `elasticsearch` output. Maybe try to use the `ID` field

```
elasticsearch {
   index => "det"
   document_type => "contact"
   document_id => "%{ID}"             <--- change this ine
   hosts => "localhost:9200"
}
```

Comment: Yes sir.But i am encountering an other problem.MySQL table has 191000 rows.When i try to execute the config file,it shows foll error:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to /home/vatsa/logstash/heapdump.hprof
Exception flushing buffer at interval! {:error=>"Java heap space" :class=>"Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError", :level=>:warn}
Error: Your application used more memory than the safety cap of 1G.
Specify -J-Xmx####m to increase it (#### = cap size in MB).
Specify -w for full OutOfMemoryError stack trace
I dint understand the error.How to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you create another question for this as this is a different issue. That way we don't cram too much into this question which is solved.